# WiFi Dropout Issue With Ubuntu 14.10-16.04?

Tags: 16.04, broadcom

I am running a 2012 MacBook Pro with a Broadcom BCM4331 wireless card. I have ran Ubuntu as my main OS on this machine since 14.04, however since 14.10 I have had issues with WiFi dropouts. I don't recall this being an issue in 14.04. I don't even really remember how far into the cycle I installed 14.04, so it could have just been that I never used it enough to encounter this issue.

I have paid close attention to this, and my WiFi seems to drop out whenever I am doing a lot of "network intensive" things so to speak and doing things that were taxing on my laptop. For example, I was once in a Hangouts video call with a friend of mine and playing a game called "Starbound" whilst driving my laptop monitor and my 27" 60Hz monitor at once, with the video being on the laptop display. In the span of about two hours I encountered 16 dropouts. My laptop had been on most of the day and I had only experienced two dropouts.

These dropouts can almost always be fixed by going into settings and turning WiFi on and off, but sometimes I have to run the following command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

My laptop is extremely close to the router and it is not a fault with the router as I can still access the Internet on my phones and so can the other people in the house. I had this problem on OS X and Apple had issued several updates claiming to fix this, but none of them ever worked for me. Are there any solutions to this? I looked around online and found no help at all.

I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, but I have had this issue with "stock" Ubuntu - Or Ubuntu with the default Unity desktop. I have spoke to other people running Ubuntu, both "spin off" distros such as Xubuntu and Lubuntu and people running standard Unity Ubuntu, and they have not had such an issue. I have a really old machine running Linux Mint and it does not have this issue. I have used Linux on a few machines in the past and have never had any issues with WiFi connectivity.

Thanks!